# RunLength Encoding - decompression (Java)

Tags: java, run-length-encoding

I am using RLE and I am trying to create a decompression program in Java. I have:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Decompress {

    public static String decode(String string) {

        StringBuffer dest = new StringBuffer();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
            matcher.find();
            while (number-- != 0) {
                dest.append(matcher.group());
            }
        }
        return dest.toString();   
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {

          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.print("Enter string: ");
          String string = sc.nextLine();
          String output = "";
          System.out.println(decode(output));
    }
}
```

But it wont work for me. I to have user input such as a2b3 and the output aabbb it cannot be hardcoded

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` throws a NumberFormatException if the string you pass it isn't an integer. Your code works fine if the input is formatted like `2a3b` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do `([a-zA-Z])([0-9]+)` as the regex.  That way you have the parts already parsed by the regex.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z])(\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String letter = matcher.group();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    while (number-- != 0) {
        dest.append(letter);
    }
    matcher.find();
}
```